# How To Find K-th Smallest Element in Multiset-sum?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

Need some help designing an algorithm to solve this problem.

Let ***a*** and ***b*** be integers with a ≤ b, and let [a,b] denote the set {a, a + 1, a + 2, ..., b}. Suppose we are given ***n*** such sets, [a<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>1</sub>],...[a<sub>n</sub>,b<sub>n</sub>], their multiset-sum is

S = {a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>1</sub> + 1,..., b<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>2</sub> + 1,...,b<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>,a<sub>n</sub> + 1, ..., b<sub>n</sub>}

For example, the multiset-sum of [5,25], [3,10], and [8,12], is

{3,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,...,25}

**Given the sets[a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>],...,[a<sub>n</sub>, b<sub>n</sub>] such that 0 ≤ a<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>i</sub> ≤ N and an integer k > 0, design an efficient algorithm that outputs the k smallest element in S, the multiset-sum of the sets. Determine the running time of the algorithm in terms of n and N.**

I've already designed two helper algorithms called FindElementsBefore(x, [a<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>1</sub>]...[a<sub>n</sub>,b<sub>n</sub>]) and FindElementsAfter(x, [a<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>1</sub>]...[a<sub>n</sub>,b<sub>n</sub>]). These both accept an element x and each of the sets and return the number of elements in S less than x and greater than x respectively.

I've been told by my professor that using these two helper methods, I should be able to solve the above problem, but I am absolutely stumped. How do I solve this?

Comment: How about a binary search?

Comment: *There exists a solution to your problem in `O(n^2)`*. Do you want better? I am not sure but maybe `O(n)` is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a binary search.**

You already know the largest and smallest values in your multiset-sum. Thus, you have an upper and lower bound for the k-th smallest element. Now you can simply recurse on the upper and lower bounds, depending on the value of `FindElementsBefore(mid, ...) <= k`.

Comment: This is the answer. Ended up with O(n log N) runtime where N is the number of distinct numbers in S and n is the total number of sets being sumed